# Stasis app not active - Asterisk error when dialing extension

Tags: asterisk, asterisk-ari

Getting this error.

asterisk stasis app not active

Dialplan:

```
same => n,Stasis(example)
```

My app name is example.js, I checked to make sure it's calling the app:

```
ari.start('example');
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was, I had forgotten to start my app:

```
node example.js
```